# Webpack aliases does not work in Vue Styleguidist

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-styleguidist, styleguidist

I am using [Vue Styleguidist](https://vue-styleguidist.github.io/) in a Nuxt.js project. Based on the Styleguidist and Webapack documents, I have configured my `styleguide.config.js` file and set some aliases:

```
module.exports = {
 ...

   webpackConfig: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '~icons': path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/icons/'),
            },
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(css?|scss|sass)(\?.*)?$/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader',
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        ],
   } 

};
```

The components are using this alias like this:

```
import FooIcon from '~icons/foo';
```

Although the Styleguide cannot resolve the address. I believe the alias in the `styleguide.config.js` is somehow being ignored.

Does anyone know how should I work around this problem?